# Add vote breakdown for iOS app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app

I recently reached over 1k rep on a site which means I can see the voting breakdowns for questions and answers which is cool.

However when using the iOS app (and Android ***I assume***) you can't see the voting breakdown (*by clicking on current vote score*) and you need to go to the full site of a web browser to see the voting scores properly.

I appreciate this isn't mission critical but with it being a feature that requires (*that much*) rep to attain, I feel it's worth adding to the mobile apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [Established User privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) at 1,000 on this site you would be able to see those vote counts on the iOS app.

I can certainly see them here by click and holding for a second or so.

Comment: It seems as if you have to press down for it to appear. With it being a single click on a computer I thought the app would only require a tap. Learnt something new. Thanks.